# concave leaf curl in the center of the tomato leafs

Tags: tomatoes

I've got some concave leaf curl going on on my indoor tomato plant. I haven't found any images that resemble this condition. The plant itself is strong as heck, got really thick, dark green leafs, planted 30cm deep 14 days ago and with the main stem cut off a week after.

These are the images. They are 6000x4000 so zoom in as much as you want. My go-to culprit is too much water or too little. What do you think?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the nervation is so thick, it loses water and then rehydrates at different rate compared to the rest of the leaf. When experiencing drought, the leaves curl downwards and when watered again, they keep this curled shape because the nervation is less flexible than a thin one.

These leaves will not return to normal shape, but if you water regularly, the younger leaves won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I am indeed going easy on watering, because I cut off the main stem. Do you have any tips on how to know if deep planted plant has enough water before it starts to curl? It is easy to touch the top soil, but that doesn't tell much about soil 30cm deep. These tomatoes are in pots, but the same question applies to garden plants.

Comment: There are instruments that measure humidity in soil, the cheapest ones come with a pHmeter and are not too precise. Just google "measure soil humidity" and remember to clean the instrument after using it, otherwise it will show incorrect readings after a few weeks.